# OpenGL is incorrectly passing vertices the vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

**Problem:** Opengl is converting the integer array, I passed into a vertex array object, into a float array for some reason.

When I try to use the vertices as an ivec2 in my vertex shader I get some weird numbers as outputs, however if I use vec2 instead I get the expected output.

**Code:**

VertexShader:

```
#version 430 core
//                         \/ This is what I'm reffering to when talking about ivec2 and vec2
layout (location = 0) in ivec2 aPos;

uniform uvec2 window;

void main()
{
    float xPos = float(aPos.x)/float(window.x);
    float yPos = float(aPos.y)/float(window.y);

    gl_Position = vec4(xPos, yPos, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Passing the Vertex Array:

```
GLint vertices[] =
{
    -50,  50,
     50,  50,
     50, -50,
    -50, -50
};

GLuint VBO, VAO;

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);  //  \/ I'm passing it as an int
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLint), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glUseProgram(sprite2DProgram);
glUniform2ui(glGetUniformLocation(sprite2DProgram, "window"), 640, 480);
```

**Output:**

The first picture is what happens when I use ivec2 (the bad output).
The second picture is what happes when I use vec2  (the expected output).
[image: What happens when I use ivec2]
[image: What happens when I use vec2 (The correct output)]

If you need to know anything else please ask it in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vertex attributes with an integral data it has to be used [**`glVertexAttribIPointer`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on the **`I`**), to define an array of generic vertex attribute data.

This means, that if you use the `ivec2` data type for the attribute in the vertex shader:

```
in ivec2 aPos;
```

then you have to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` wehan you define the array of generic vertex attribute data.

Change your code like this, to solve the issue:

```
// glVertexAttribIPointer instead of glVertexAttribPointer
glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLint), (void*)0);
```

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.2. CURRENT VERTEX ATTRIBUTE VALUES; page m389](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf):

> When values for a vertex shader attribute variable are sourced from an enabled generic vertex attribute array,
>   the array must be specified by a command compatible with the data type of the variable. 
>   The values loaded into a shader attribute variable bound to generic attribute index are undefined if the array for index was not specified by:
>
> - VertexAttribFormat, for floating-point base type attributes;
> - VertexAttribIFormat with type BYTE, SHORT, or INT for signed integer base type attributes; or
> - VertexAttribIFormat with type UNSIGNED_BYTE, UNSIGNED_SHORT, or UNSIGNED_INT for unsigned integer base type attributes.

Comment: I had been trying to debug that problem for days now. Thank you.